# Pass prop as module name when mapping to namespaced module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm trying to pass the store module namespace via props to a component. When I try and map to getters with the prop, it throws this error,

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object**

If I pass the name as a string it works.

**This Works**

```
<script>
export default {

  props: ['store'],

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('someString', [
      'filters'
    ])
  }
}
</script>
```

**This does not work**

this.store is defined 
this.store typeof is a String

```
<script>
  export default {

    props: ['store'],

    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(this.store, [
        'filters'
      ])
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Here I am June 2020 looking at my old question to see if It was answered. Still no solution.

Comment: Looking for a solution to this as well. Created another topic as well to hopefully get some traction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287347/specify-vuex-store-to-use-in-component/64287578#64287578

Answer (score 1):

I used this style utilising beforeCreate to access the variables you want, I used the props passed into the component instance:

```js
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from "vuex";
import module from '@/store/modules/mymod';

export default {
  name: "someComponent",
  props: ['namespace'],
  beforeCreate() { 
    let namespace = this.$options.propsData.namespace;
    const { mapActions, mapState } = createNamespacedHelpers(namespace);

    // register your module first
    this.$store.registerModule(namespace, module);

    // now that createNamespacedHelpers can use props we can now use neater mapping
    this.$options.computed = {
      ...mapState({
        name: state => state.name,
        description: state => state.description
      }),

      // because we use spread operator above we can still add component specifics
      aFunctionComputed(){ return this.name + "functions";},
      anArrowComputed: () => `${this.name}arrows`,
    };

    // set up your method bindings via the $options variable
    this.$options.methods = {
      ...mapActions(["initialiseModuleData"])
    };
  },

  created() {
    // call your actions passing your payloads in the first param if you need
    this.initialiseModuleData({ id: 123, name: "Tom" });
  }
}
```

I personally use a helper function in the module I'm importing to get a namespace, so if I hadmy module storing projects and passed a projectId of 123 to my component/page using router and/or props it would look like this:

```js
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from "vuex";
import projectModule from '@/store/project.module';

export default{
  props['projectId'], // eg. 123
  ...
  beforeCreate() {

    // dynamic namespace built using whatever module you want:
   let namespace = projectModule.buildNamespace(this.$options.propsData.projectId); // 'project:123'

   // ... everything else as above with no need to drop namespaces everywhere
   this.$options.computed = {
      ...mapState({
        name: state => state.name,
        description: state => state.description
      })
   }
  }
}
```

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

I tackled this problem for hours, too. Then I finally came up with one idea.

- Add `attachStore` function in a child vue component. A function nama is not important. Any name is ok except vue reserved word.

  ```
  export default {
    :
    attachStore (namespace) {
      Object.assign(this.computed, mapGetters(namespace, ['filters']))
    }
  }
  ```
- When this vue component is imported, call `attachStore` with namespace parameter. Then use it at parent components attributes.

  ```
  import Child from './path/to/child'

  Child.attachStore('someStoresName')

  export default {
    name: 'parent',
    components: { Child }
    :
  }
  ```

Comment: You could also call attachStore from your child's `activated()` and pass the namespace to it using a prop. That could be a bit more Vue-ish

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering is being thrown during Vue/Vuex's initialization process, `this.store` cannot be converted because it doesn't exist yet. I haven't had to work with namespacing yet, and this is untested so I don't know if it will work, but you may be able to solve this problem by having an intermediary like this:

```
<script>
  export default {

    props: ['store'],

    data {
        namespace: (this.store !== undefined) ? this.store : 'null',
    },

    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(this.namespace, [
        'filters'
      ])
    }
  }
</script>
```

That ternary expression will return a string if `this.store` is undefined, if it isn't undefined then it will return the value in `this.store`.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I think that you are on the right track but your solution didn't work for me. I'm still seeing the same error.

Comment: That doesn't work, it seems like the namespace passed to `mapGetters` is only evaluated once, before any properties are available

Answer (score -1):

Note that there is also a discussion about this on Vue's Github page here: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/863

Until Vue formally supports it, I replaced something like

```
...mapState({
  foo: state => state.foo
})
```

with

```
foo () {
  return this.$store.state[this.namespace + '/foo'] || 0
}
```

Where `namespace` is passed to my child component using a prop:

```
props: {
  namespace: { type: String, required: true }
}
```