# Specify Vuex Store To Use In Component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

I have modularized my Vuex store and need child-components to be able to access data/use the same stores as their parent component.

Here's what I've tried:

```html
<!-- ParentOne.vue -->
<template>
<div>
  <child-component
    vuex-store="services/opportunities"
  />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from '@/components/services/child-components/ChildComponent';
import { mapActions, mapState, mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    components: {
        'child-component': ChildComponent,
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapState('services/opportunities', {
            statusListOpportunities: 'statusListOpportunities',
        }),
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<!-- ChildComponent.vue -->
<template>
<div>
  <!-- Content -->
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapState, mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    props: {
        vuexStore: {
            type: String,
        },
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapState(this.vuexStore, {
            statusListOpportunities: 'statusListOpportunities',
        }),
    }
}
</script>
```

And here's the error I'm getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vuexStore' of undefined

I've been passing down props, but the prop juggling is getting chaotic and it would be much easier if I could just specify which store a component should use.

I also not able to specify the store directly in the child component since ParentTwo.vue may use a different store such as `services/cases`.

Anyone have any idea why this wouldn't work. I'm open to alternative solutions as well.

Comment: `...mapState(this.vuexStore, ...)` it should encounter wrong context issue

Answer (score 0):

Look into the function=`myMapState` in below demo, the usage=`...mapState(this.vuexStore, ...)` encountered wrong context issue (`this` is not the component instance).

One solution is directly access `this.$store.state` in the function of computed property as what computed property=`test2` does in below demo.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
let myMapState = function (options, test) {
   !test && console.error(test)
   return Vuex.mapState(options)
}
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    theme: "light",
    good: true
  }
})
Vue.component('v-test', {
  template: `<div><p>1: {{test1}}: {{test2}}</p><p>2: {{theme1}}</p></div>`,
  props: ['vuexStore'],
  computed: {
    ...myMapState({'test1': this.vuexStore, 'theme1': 'theme'}, this.vuexStore),
    test2: function () {
      return this.$store.state[this.vuexStore]
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <v-test :vuex-store="'theme'"></v-test>
    <v-test :vuex-store="'good'"></v-test>
  </div>
</div>
```